# How to create list as a parameter in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a report in 2005 SSRS which I want to add a parameter to. The parameter would be comprised of a group of zip codes, but be selected as a single item in the list.

For example, I would like to have 5 zip codes as one selection in the list and 3 for another, etc:

```
Select 11111,22222,33333,44444,55555,66666 AS Boondock
Select 77777,88888,99999 AS Timbuck
Select Zip Codes NOT IN (11111-99999) AS Everything Else
```

So my selections in the dropdown would be:

Boondock

Timbuck

Everything Else

Can anyone help me with how I should go about creating this parameter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution here would probably to use a Calculated Field on your dataset, called LocationDescription, for example:

```
=SWITCH(Fields!ZipCode >= 11111 and Fields!ZipCode <= 66666, "Boondock", Fields!ZipCode >= 77777 and Fields!ZipCode <= 99999, "Timbuck",True, "Everywhere Else")
```

The lone true statement at the end is due to the SWITCH expression reading left-to-right and exiting once it evaluates one of the switches as TRUE. This way for each of the items in your table of ZipCodes you will always end up with a TRUE result.

I assume you're evaluating a range of ZipCodes, and not exact values of 11111,22222, and so on? If so, the switch will have more values. A sample of your data would help if you want an exact answer.

Once you have built your Calculated Field, you can then set up a Parameter (called @LocationParameter) with available values based on a query of your LocationDescription field, then just filter your dataset using:

Expression:
= Fields!LocationDescription

Operator: =

Value:
 @LocationParameter

(if you want multiple selections on your parameter, change the operator to IN)

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I don't think I can use the switch because I am evaluating exact zip code values, so 11112 would not be in the region considered Boondock. Or would I just use =SWITCH(Fields!ZipCode = 11111 OR 22222 OR 33333 etc, "Boondock",...

Comment: The SWITCH I have written would evaluate any Zip between 11111 and 66666 as Boondock, so 11112 would be included. You may need to CDbl your ZipCode field for it to be evaluated correctly as a number (if you have entered the field as Text in your DB).

Comment: Sorry, I see what you mean now. 11112 should not be classed as Boondock. In which case, yes use the OR options you have mentioned. You will have to explicitly write Fields!ZipCode = for each value.

Comment: For completeness:

`=SWITCH(Fields!ZipCode = 11111 OR Fields!ZipCode = 22222 OR Fields!ZipCode = 33333 OR OR Fields!ZipCode = 44444 OR OR Fields!ZipCode = 55555 OR Fields!ZipCode = 66666, "Boondock", Fields!ZipCode = 77777 OR Fields!ZipCode = 88888 OR Fields!ZipCode <= 99999, "Timbuck",True, "Everywhere Else")`

Comment: You could also do this with a dataset, but you will still need to build an expression that evaluates "Everything Else".

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a simple string parameter to present to the user. Let's call it `ZipCodeSet`.
2. Create a dataset that examines the `@ZipCodeSet` parameter and returns the appropriate list of zip codes. Call it `ZipCodeSelection`.
3. Create an internal multivaue parameter that uses `ZipCodeSelection` as both its Available Values and Default Values. Call it `SelectedZipCodes`.
4. Use `SelectedZipCodes` in your report's datasets.